# Storing array of data into multiple rows to database using Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, database, checkbox, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having problems storing array of data into multiple rows to the database.

In my form (assign.blade.php), I have multiple checkboxes, where users can choose multiple boxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="adminbox[]" value='{{ $value->id }}'>
```

Inside my controller (SchoolController.php), I have this code:

```
public function assignadmin()
{
   $adminbox = implode(",", Input::get('adminbox'));
   for($a=0;$a<count($adminbox);$a++)
   {        
     $AC = new AccessControlEntry;
     $AC->ProfileID=$adminbox[$a];
     $AC->save();
   } 
return Redirect::to('school/view');
}
```

I believe that the loop should be going through the array and storing each of the data in the array into multiple rows in the database. But however, I got this error instead:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `accesscontrols` (`ProfileID`) values (U))

For example, if there are 3 data in an array, they should be stored into 3 different rows in the database. 
Can anyone assist me in achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
$adminbox = Input::get('adminbox');
```

Instead of:

```
$adminbox = implode(",", Input::get('adminbox'));
```

Because `$adminbox` will be an array of checked `checkbox` values like:

```
// dd($adminbox);
array (size=2)
  0 => string '1' (length=1) // For value = 1
  1 => string '2' (length=1) // For value = 2
```

Also make sure you have `checked` checkboxes available before manipulate them, like:

```
$adminbox = Input::get('adminbox');
if($adminbox) {
    // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Alright, I've made the following changes as mentioned by you. It seems that the loop is not iterating through the data in the array and storing them into multiple rows. Instead, I'm receiving an error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into accesscontrols (ProfileID) values (U10))